# Записать информацию в файл из метода

Tags: c#

Есть такой метод

```
public void TableHead()
{
    Console.Write("╔");
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) Console.Write("═");
    Console.Write("╦");
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) Console.Write("═");
    Console.Write("╦");
    for (int i = 0; i < n3; i++) Console.Write("═");
    Console.WriteLine("╗");
    string s = "║{0,-" + n1.ToString() + "}║{1,-" + n2.ToString() + "}║{2,-" + n3.ToString() + "}║";
    Console.WriteLine(s, "Фамилия", "Продолжительность пребывания", "Возраст");
    Console.Write("╠");
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) Console.Write("═");
    Console.Write("╬");
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) Console.Write("═");
    Console.Write("╬");
    for (int i = 0; i < n3; i++) Console.Write("═");
    Console.WriteLine("╣");
}
```

Как из мейна записать его в файл? Вот так не выходит.

```
using (StreamWriter sw=new StreamWriter(@"newdata.txt",true,Encoding.Unicode))
{                
    sw.WriteLine(tab.TableHead());                
}
```

Comment: Так, стоп. А вы ж не возвращаете никакую строку, которую надо записывать в файл... вы все в консоль только вываливаете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы записать данные в файл, нужно в метод `WriteLine` передать строку, которую хотите записать.

Ваш метод `TableHead()` ничего не возвращает, а только рисует что-то в консоли.

Как минимум среда разработки должна была вам подсветить проблемное место и указать, что там проблемы. И даже не должно было скомпилироваться. Странно, что этого не произошло. Или вы не обращаете на это внимание.

Как бы то ни было, вам нужно сделать так, чтоб метод возвращал строку

```
public String TableHead() {
    // do smth.
}
```

При этом так как вы там работаете со строками, и даже в цикле что-то строите, то желательно воспользоваться [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx), добавляя в него все необходимое. И в конце вернуть строку.

Примерный пример:

```
public String TableHead() {
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("╔");

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) 
        builder.Append("=");

    builder.Append("╦");

    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) 
        builder.Append("=");

    builder.Append("╦");

    // ...
    // и так далее
    // ...

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

---

**P.S**

Чтоб не превращалась в кашу логика вывода в консоль и запись в билдер и вывод в файл сделайте логику как-то раздельно, например интерфейс `IWritable`, с методом `writeTo`. Два класса `MyConsoleWriter` и `MyFileWriter` с имплементированием этого интерфейса и прописыванием логики для данного метода. А в методах своей программы, в таких как `TableHead()` и прочих (что у вас там, наверное `TableBody90`, `TableFooter()` и т.д.) все складывайте в какую-то переменную накопительную...В итоге, когда понадобиться прописать что-то в файл, достаточно будет написать `(new MyFileWriter).writeTo('fileName.fileExt', builder.ToString())`, а чтоб вывести на консоль: `(new MyConsoleWriter).writeTo(Console, builder.ToString())`. На вскидку. Хотя можно даже все придумать получше.

Comment: Не совсем такой подход работает, объясню почему. Вообще это один из 3-ех методов, который будет строить наглядную табличку, данный метод строит шапку. И в чем собственно проблема, он состоит не из одной строки, а 3ех,: верхняя линия шапки, затем строка с данными(в моем случае фамилия возраст и т.д.) и нижняя линия шапки. Как итог в файл выводится всё в одну строку. Это одна проблема, вторая.     `string s = "║{0,-" + n1.ToString() + "}║{1,-" + n2.ToString() + "}║{2,-" + n3.ToString() + "}║";`    `Console.WriteLine(s, "Фамилия", "Продолжительность пребывания", "Возраст");`

Comment: Эти 2 строчки у меня отвечали за то, что бы данные отображались каждый в своем столбце ( у меня их 3 ) я эти строки подстроил под Ваш способ таким образом `string s = "║{0,-" + n1.ToString() + "}║{1,-" + n2.ToString() + "}║{2,-" + n3.ToString() + "}║";`    `builder.Append(s+"Фамилия"+"Продолжительность пребывания"+"Возраст");`  как итог у меня в файле, вместо того, что бы данные отображались на определенном расстоянии такая вот строчка `║{0,-13}║{1,-30}║{2,-13}║ФамилияПродолжительность пребыванияВозраст`, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков угу. просто вам надо основы языка подучить и тогда все будет нормально. Как пример: для новой строки у билдера применяется `AppendLine()`.......а для того, чтобы добавить форматированную строку используется `AppendFormat()` .......ссылку на билдер я вам дал, там все написано... ....и кстати разделите логику вывода в консоль и в файл....все складывайте  какую нибудь переменную, а потом для отрисовки в консоль используйте какой-либо метод `Draw()`....а для записи в файл - другой...

Comment: Благодарю, теперь все стало на свои места!